# RF Rx with NodeMCU error

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, rf

I am using RF Tx with Arduino Uno and Rx with NodeMCU. I use RF switch library. At the recipient side if I use an Arduino Uno MCU. I can receive the output, but with NodeMCU I have a blank serial monitor; no output is shown. RF.enable (0) is used in my code and pin D2 is connected to data of RF module.

Some one help me please.

Comment: why not RF.enable(D2)?

Comment: The RF.enable(0) is the actual code line given in the example section .. will try what you have suggested.

Comment: Pin D2 is GPIO4 ... does the `(0)` specify the GPIO pin the RF module is connected to - if so, that's the problem ... either use `(4)` or `(D2)`